# Whats with the big gap halfway down my page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My page is [here](http://davidspeightphotography.co.uk/wordpress/?page_id=56).  The section I am on about starts with CANVAS FINE ART WRAPS, you will notice between the first and second paragraph there is a big gap.  I have looked at it on chrome (osx), safari(osx) and firefox(windows)

There's nothing in the markup to suggest the reason for it.  Inspecting it shows no margin or anything causing it.[image]

Comment: It looks ok for me (Safari OSX) but without any code we can't really help at all.

Comment: I'm looking at it on safari osx too and I can see the gap.  The code is just a <p>text</p> then another <p>text</p>

Comment: There seems to be no gap, I'm using Firefox 12(Linux)

Comment: I see the gap, and your markup validates and your css looks alright, that is very weird :D

Comment: oh good you can see it!  Thought I was going mad there.

Comment: I'm on firefox 13 by the way, i see it in chrome 18 as well. This is very baffling, there is no sign of anything wrong.

Comment: It's done in wordpress so I'm wondering if wordpress is adding in some blank spaces between the <p>s

Comment: If I had to guess. I would say this was done in php and you are looking at BOM. Try re-encoding the page as UTF-8 without BOM in your text editor.

Comment: @tw16 erm, how do I do that?  I'm using the html editor in wordpress

Comment: Ahh then that might not be the case. It sounds like wordpress is sticking in something it shouldn't be. My suggestion would be: Go into html view, cut out all of the code, paste it into note pad, save the page as completely empty and then copy back the elements one by one into your html view and save. I've put it in a solution below.

Comment: ha!  That fixed it.  All I did was copy it into notepad then copy that and paste it back in, save and it sorted it.  Dam wordpress.  Have to use it though so client can edit it.  Don't know if you want to add that as an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Wordpress is sticking in something it shouldn't be. My suggestion would be:

- Go into html view
- Cut out all of the code
- Paste it into notepad
- Save the page as completely empty
- Copy back the elements one by one into your html view and save.

Comment: @Nicola: Happy I could help to fix it. What a weird bug!

Comment: The "something" is two ['LINE SEPARATOR' (U+2028)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm). No idea how that could have got there.

Comment: @thirtydot How did you see that?  IS there some sort of hidden text thing you can paste it into?

Comment: @thirtydot: That is just disappointing! I thought you used your legendary super powers!

Comment: @thirtydot that looks confusing looking at it, is it easy to use once downloaded just for checking text?

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `.box p` selector. It should work after this.

Comment: you cant make P element  - an inline element  - thisis wrong !

Comment: This might be a way to hide the issue. But it doesn't really get to the bottom of why it is going wrong.

Comment: No entirely sure. But I noticed that your paragraphs had display block, even tough they are inline elements. So it probably some bug with block elements nested one after other without being floated. It should also work if you set them to display: inline, or keep them block elements but float them left.

Comment: `p`s are not inline elements! They are naturally `block` elements.

Comment: paragraphs aren't inline elements, they're block elements, and they don't have to be floated!

Comment: A block element has some whitespace above and below it. So at this point Husar is right. `inline-block` means The element is placed as an inline element, but it behaves as a block element. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: @Libin: My response was in relation to his comment: `I noticed that your paragraphs had display block, even tough they are inline elements.`

Comment: @tw16 ok cool. =) Anyway the problem solved. Its just some bad characters in his html.

Answer (score 1):

the p has a margin  - which should be reduced

also , the box class should reduce its line height.

### edit

Also - ive edited your text to  : 1111 and 2222 and it was fine

you probably pasted the text which contains some bad chars

Comment: Yeah, this is the right answer. If you remove the line-height of the box class, and the margin of the p-element, the gap is gone.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Even if you remove the line height and the paragraph margins there is still a gap.

Comment: @Nicola why the link is down ?

Comment: don't know, I'm panicking a bit!

Comment: what do you mean you've edited my text to :1111, what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is on line 199/200 of your normalise.css file:

it has:

```
p, pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

If I remove this, the big gap is removed.